# Refresh design of WEB-INF/classes in Lotus Domino environment

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, web-inf

i've some classes deployed in WEB-INF/classes.
When i refresh design database on production, this classes are not updated?
Why?

Comment: Do you have their sources in database? If not, you should use JARs, not CLASS files...

Comment: Sources are in WebContent/WEB-INF/src of database...do i need to use a jar?

Comment: No, if sources are there, no need to use JARs. Make sure the template you are refreshing from is built.

Comment: And sources are updated?

Comment: Yes, it's built ("Build automatically" checked), but no update happens during refresh. Classes are all in my pakage explorer under WebContent/WEB-INF/src folder

Comment: What version on Domino Designer are you using? And if you check in Navigator, do you see .class files in WEB-INF folder?

Comment: Release 8.5.2 - Folder "classes" in WEB-INF is present.

Comment: I'd suggest to try with 8.5.3 FP4 (and latest fixes) or even FP5. Also, you can check http://www.runningnotes.net/index.php/2013/08/29/mystery-application-breakage/ for some tips. On another note, you can use NotesPeek to check if you java design elements are up-to-date and present.

Comment: There is a trick to make a view showing all design elements. We adopted it as standard to be included in every database - it addresses many deployment problems - for example "Prohibit refresh/replace" flags turned on for design elements which have no way to turn it on/off in designer interface. http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/view-of-design-elements.htm

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the server version you need to take a "brute force" attack:

- Instead of refresh design use replace design
- Use a small agent that removes the Java design elements before the refresh/replace operation (they are stored in regular design note entries

The failure might happen when the classes are currently loaded

Answer (score 0):

Try to make Clean on production database after design refresh. That will wipe class files and compile them from sources. From that moment on there should be no problem with next refresh.